# Migrating a Craft site to a different host.

Tags: database, error

I'm moving my site from one host to another, and I'm having some trouble moving my craft site over. I have all of the files moved, and in the config file I'm pointing to the new database which I've imported over already. But when I go to the site or the admin url I'm getting a 500 error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it a Craft-styled 500 error or an Apache styled one?  If Craft, the underlying error will be in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`. If Apache, it'll be in your Apache error logs.

Comment: No problem... did that lead to you fixing the issue?  If so, would you mind posting an answer with some of the details?

Comment: Yeah, it was in the Craft Logs. I found out it was a Database connection issue. I had the incorrect database host name for my database. It was supposed to be localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP's comment, there was a database connection error in the Craft log files. Once that was corrected it solved the 500 Internal Server Error.